# Multiple User Types - Spring Security Configuration

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-oauth2

We have several user types

- Internal Users (authenticated using Active Directory)
- External Users/Clients (stored in the DB1)
- External Users/Vendors (stored in the DB2)

We plan to use Spring Security OAuth2 to generate GWT token that can then be used to call set of webservices

I can use multiple AuthenticationProviders (LDAPAuthenticationProvider and two DAOAuthenticationProviders) but then we will loose ability to have user to be BOTH client and vendor for example (if they use SAME email for authentication). Since it will stop polling providers once authentication is successful.

I can also use profiles @Profile="vendor/client" and start auth server specifically for Client or Vendor authentication - but that means two different processes = more maintenance.

Any other ideas ? Anybody ran into something similar?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options I can think of:

1 - If each different type of user uses a different client ID, then set something in the client details when you load them to show how the user should be authenticated for the client. There's a getAdditionalInformation() method on ClientDetails that returns a Map you can use to store this info

```
/**
 * Additional information for this client, not needed by the vanilla OAuth protocol but might be useful, for example,
 * for storing descriptive information.
 * 
 * @return a map of additional information
 */
Map<String, Object> getAdditionalInformation();
```

2 - Pass in a header or request param that the AuthenticationProvider can then use to determine how to authenticate that user. You'll need to configure your own implementation of WebAuthenticationDetails to retrieve this information from the request.

This should then be available by calling getDetails() on the Authentication object passed into the AuthenticationProvider's authenticate() method.